# Get HTML text from TextView/EditText, then uppercase

Tags: android, html, android-studio, textview, android-edittext

I need to get **HTML formatted texts** from `TextView`/`EditText` components, then I'd like to transform them (programmatically) to uppercase, under a specific user parameter, checking two list of components included in a `ViewGroup` object:

```
//These custom functions return ArrayList of components
ArrayList<EditText> myEditTextList = getAllEditText(viewGroup);
ArrayList<TextView> myTextViewList = getAllTextView(viewGroup);

for (EditText et : myEditTextList) {
    //At this point, I'm expecting "Welcome to <b>My World</b>" or similar, but I'm getting "Welcome to My World"
    String original_text = et.getText().toString();
    et.setText(Html.fromHtml(original_text.toUpperCase());
}
for (TextView tv : myTextViewList) {
    //Same as before
}
```

I checked some topics here but I wasn't able to find any working solution about this issue.

Note: I know that `Html` class is inefficient, but my issue is actually about *getting* more than *setting*.

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

```java
dataBinding!!.tvHtml.setText(
    Html.fromHtml(
       "Testing text. <b>Bold Value</b>. Normal text."
    ),
    TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE)
val htmlText = Html.toHtml(
        dataBinding!!.tvHtml.editableText
).toString()
Log.e("TAG", "init: " + htmlText)
```

Comment: Please explain your code

Comment: I already tried to use `getEditableText()` function from TextView object, but it returns `null`

Comment: I'm already using this, its working fine.

Comment: @mousetail any problem is this code?

Comment: No, but on SO we don't consider code-only answers high quality, it needs to include a explanation